# Where to securely store SSL certificates for Node js web service

Tags: java, node.js, ssl, redhat, keystore

cant find a definitive answer to this online. I have a node js api service running on a Linux Redhat enterprise machine. I stored the ssl keys in just a normal directory folder /home/ssl/keys (have feeling its not safe to do this). My co-worker advise that I use java Keystore to store the keys instead. There is literally no relationship between Java keystore and node js that I have found online.

Is there an alternative for node js to securely store ssl certificates similar to java keystore?What is a best practice when it comes to securing ssl certificates in a production environment? Whats the downside of simply saving the keys in a random folder on the server?

Thanks.

Comment: This already have an answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/648364/189624)